cypress test is not finding method
I am new with cypress and testing
now I have a cypress test like this :
import Description from '../Description.vue'
const balancedMessage = 'The text is balanced.'
const UnbalancedMessage = 'The text is not balanced.'

describe('Description Component | src/components/Description.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(Description)
    cy.spy(Description.methods, 'isBalanced').as('isBalanced');
  })
  context('Validation', ()=>{
    it('Passing a balanced text with no special character', ()=>{
        cy.get('input#description').type('Hi How are you doing today?')
        cy.contains(balancedMessage)
        cy.callsIsBalancedOnce()
    })
  })
})

and this is my Vuejs3 component
<template>
    <input id="description" v-model="description" />
{{ message }}
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref,computed } from 'vue'

// states
const description = ref('')
const sepcialChars = ['(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}']
const balancedMessage = 'The text is balanced.'
const UnbalancedMessage = 'The text is not balanced.'

//computed
const message = computed(() => isBalanced() ? balancedMessage : UnbalancedMessage)

// methods
function isBalanced() {
    const strArr = description.value.split('')
    let isBalnce = true
    let caps = []
    for (let s of strArr) {
        // caps special char
        if (isSepcial(s)) {
            const isOpen = isOpening(s)
            if (isOpen) {
                caps.push(s)
            } else { // closing
                const lastCap = caps[caps.length - 1]
                if (lastCap === findPair(s))
                    caps.pop()
                else
                    isBalnce = false

            }
        }
    }

    if (caps.length) isBalnce = false
    return isBalnce
}
function isSepcial(character) {
    return sepcialChars.includes(character)
}
// get sepcial char and return true if
// it's opening and false if closing
function isOpening(sepcialChar) {
    const index = sepcialChars.indexOf(sepcialChar)
    return index % 2 === 0
}
function findPair(sepcialChar) {
    const index = sepcialChars.indexOf(sepcialChar)
    const pairIndex = index - 1
    return sepcialChars[pairIndex]
}
</script>

and it contain isBalanced() method
the problem is that when I try to run cypress test like this
npm run test:unit:dev

I face this error :
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBalanced')

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Description Component 

but as you see isBalanced exit in the component !
what's the problem and How can i fix this ?

The problem is that the Description component is using the isBalanced() function indirectly, via the computed() watcher.
At the time cy.mount(Description) is run, the computed watcher is set up with the original isBalanced() function.
Then you run cy.spy(Description.methods, 'isBalanced') and it replaces the component property isBalanced with a wrapper function that counts the calls and invokes the original function - but it is too late, the watcher is already set.

To remedy that, you can re-instantiate the message watcher after the spy has been set
let component;

before(() => {
  cy.mount(Description).then(response => {
    component = response.component
  })
})

it('Passing a balanced text with no special character', () => {

  cy.spy(component, 'isBalanced').as('isBalanced')       // set the spy

  cy.then(() => {
    // re-set the computed
    component.message = computed(() => component.isBalanced() ? balancedMessage : unbalancedMessage)
  })

  cy.get('input#description').type('Hi How are you doing today?')
  cy.contains(balancedMessage)

  cy.get('@isBalanced')
    .its('callCount')
    .should('eq', 27)    
})



Just look at the effect on component or DOM
IMO it's probably sufficient to look at the effect on the message property
it('testing isBalanced', () => {

  cy.get('input#description').type('Brackets "()" are balanced')
  cy.wrap(component).its('message').should('eq', balancedMessage)
  // or
  cy.contains(balancedMessage)

  cy.get('input#description').type('Brackets "(" are not balanced')
  cy.wrap(component).its('message').should('eq', unbalancedMessage)
  // or
  cy.contains(unbalancedMessage)
})



thanks , but I am not supposed to modify the test

You prefer a failing test to a working test?
